# Plotting : Can't get log axis to work (with Shiny + GGvis + Dplyr)

Tags: r, plot, dplyr, ggvis, shiny

I have some code written for a reactive shiny app, which has variable axes.
I get them to display just as I want, except for one thing. I need both axes to be on a log-scale instead of linear. I found solutions as `trans = "log"` but that causes my graph to show up empty. Any solutions?

The code i have for plotting (if i change `log` to `linear`, its works):

```
vis <- reactive({
  # Labels for axes
  xvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$xvar]
  yvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$yvar]

  xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
  yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))

  gegevens %>%
    ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
    layer_points(size := 50, size.hover := 200,
                 fillOpacity := 0.2, fillOpacity.hover := 0.5,
                 stroke = ~bron, key := ~Project.ID) %>%
    add_tooltip(gegevens_tooltip, "hover") %>%
    add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
    add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
    add_legend("stroke", title = "Gegevens van:", values = c("A", "B")) %>%
    scale_numeric("x", trans = "log") %>%
    scale_numeric("y", trans = "log") %>%
    scale_nominal("stroke", domain = c("A", "B"),
                  range = c("blue", "#aaa")) %>%
    set_options(width = 600, height = 600)
})

vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
```

Comment: Does your data have zero or negative values?

Comment: it shows value, on the very left corner of the graph, i can see 1 dot. it also tells me the amount of rows selected, and those are around 1400 with the standard selection, so i should see 1400 dots. With linear i do see all the dots. not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm betting its something with presenting the data instead of having the data to present

Comment: I'm asking about the zero and negative values since the log for those are undefined. So any data that is zero or negative will not show in your graph (possibly with a message or warning). It's hard to help without an example that is reproducible. Does the `ggvis` work outside of `shiny`?

Comment: there are no 0, negative or unknown values. The range is from 0.14 to 2000 for A and also for B. i found that adding expand = 0 give me the points in the graph as wanted. Though i need to find out how to adjust the value presented on the axis to be set instead of 2e+0 ..2e+3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding expand to the code its becomes a log scale.
i also admit format="d", grid=FALSE to add_axis so it looked a bit better.
still not satisfied with the values on the axis, but that's an other question.

code i replaced:

```
add_axis("x", title = xvar_name, format='d', grid = FALSE) %>%

scale_numeric("x", trans = "log", expand=0) %>%
```